# Efficient standard basis vector with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given an index and a size, is there a more efficient way to produce the [standard basis vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis):

```
import numpy as np
np.array([1.0 if i == index else 0.0 for i in range(size)])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
x = np.zeros(size)
x[index] = 1.0
```

at least i think thats it...

```
>>> t = timeit.Timer('np.array([1.0 if i == index else 0.0 for i in range(size)]
)','import numpy as np;size=10000;index=5123')
>>> t.timeit(10)
0.039461429317952934  #original method
>>> t = timeit.Timer('x=np.zeros(size);x[index]=1.0','import numpy as np;size=10000;index=5123')
>>> t.timeit(10)
9.4077963240124518e-05 #zeros method
>>> t = timeit.Timer('x=np.eye(1.0,size,index)','import numpy as np;size=10000;index=5123')
>>> t.timeit(10)
0.0001398340635319073 #eye method
```

looks like np.zeros is fastest...

Comment: Interestingly enough, neither of us was consistent with our whitespace around `=` (I've updated mine).

Comment: heh there fixed the whitespace :P

Answer (score 22):

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [9]: size = 5

In [10]: index = 2

In [11]: np.eye(1,size,index)
Out[11]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Hm, unfortunately, using np.eye for this is rather slow:

```
In [12]: %timeit np.eye(1,size,index)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.68 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit a = np.zeros(size); a[index] = 1.0
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 us per loop
```

---

Wrapping `np.zeros(size); a[index] = 1.0` in a function makes only a modest difference, and is still much faster than `np.eye`:

```
In [24]: def f(size, index):
   ....:     arr = np.zeros(size)
   ....:     arr[index] = 1.0
   ....:     return arr
   ....: 

In [27]: %timeit f(size, index)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 us per loop
```

Comment: Wow.  I looked at eye, and skipped over it because the documentation says: "Return a 2-D array with ones on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere."  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I thought something like this would be possible, but I'm a little surprised numpy uses `eye` for this (as the name implies it is the identity matrix and this is definitely not an identity matrix).  +1 for a better answer than mine though.

Comment: @NeilG: Hm, maybe this is not such a good solution. The timeit results show it is 5x slower than mgilson and JoranBeasley's solutions.

Comment: @unutbu: would you mind comparing it where the other solution is wrapped up in a function that accepts size and index?  (I just did, and it is only 2 time slower with my machine).

Comment: @unutbu: Thank you very much for being so thorough with this answer (and many of your other good ones).

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this is faster, but it's definitely more clear to me.

```
a = np.zeros(size)
a[index] = 1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Often, you need not one but *all* basis vectors. If this is the case, consider `np.eye`:

```
basis = np.eye(3)
for vector in basis:
  ...
```

Not exactly the same, but closely related: This even works to get a set of basis matrices with a bit of tricks:

```
>>> d, e = 2, 3    # want 2x3 matrices
>>> basis = np.eye(d*e,d*e).reshape((d*e,d,e))
>>> print(basis)
[[[ 1.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  1.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.]]]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the fastest, but the method [`scipy.signal.unit_impulse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.unit_impulse.html) generalizes the above concept to numpy arrays of any shape.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to implement this is :

```
>>> def f(size, index):
...     return (np.arange(size) == index).astype(float)
...
```

Which gives a slightly slower execution time :

```
>>> timeit.timeit('f(size, index)', 'from __main__ import f, size, index', number=1000000)
2.2554846050043125
```