# Numpy: Storing standard basis vector in a memory efficient way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975146/efficient-standard-basis-vector-with-numpy) was the only question I found about standard basis vectors in numpy but it's not really related to my question.

I have a numpy array of integers and I want to determine the co-occurrence matrix which stores the number of times indicies have the same value in the same column. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243595/pandas-counting-index-pairwise-occurrences-of-same-value-in-a-dataframe/45245622?noredirect=1#comment77472142_45245622) question describes the problem in more detail.

I have a method of solving my problem but it doesn't scale well.

**My question then is this:**

*Is it possible to store standard basis vectors in a numpy array in a memory efficient manner?*

I want to be able to do the following:

Given an array

```
M = e1  e2  e1
    e1  e2  e2
    e3  e1  e3
    e2  e3  e3
```

where `ei` is the transposed `i-th` standard basis vector of the vector space (R3 in this case), perform matrix multiplication with the transpose of `M`, i.e. determine `np.dot(M, M.T)`. To be clear, the matrix `M` above could be written as:

```
M = 1  0  0   0  1  0   1  0  0
    1  0  0   0  1  0   0  1  0
    0  0  1   1  0  0   0  0  1
    0  1  0   0  0  1   0  0  1
```

(extra spaces added for emphasis).

The issue with representing the matrix like this is that it isn't scalable in memory with the number of rows and dimension of the vector space.

**EDIT:** I should mention that the number of columns can increase as well. The memory complexity is `D * R * C` where `D` is the dimension of the vector space, `R` is the number of rows and `C` is the number of columns. In an average working example I have roughly `D == 150, R == 2000 and C == 1000` though `R` can go up to `20,000` and `C` is unbounded (though `10,000` is a reasonable estimate).

The rules for standard basis vector multiplication are simple (`ei * ei.T == 1, ei * ej.T == 0 if i != j`) so I was wondering if it's possible to store these rules in a numpy array to save memory.

Comment: What do you mean by_"The issue with representing the matrix like this is that it isn't scalable in memory with the number of rows and dimension of the vector space"_? Could you please show an example of poor scalability?

Comment: @AGNGazer Edited to show memory complexity.

Comment: Maybe the better question here is: why store a potentially massive matrix that you can easily auto-generate?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I'm not familiar with auto-generation. Can you briefly elaborate on how it could solve this problem?

Comment: @duncster94 At a high level the idea is that you do your calculations on the fly. Since these aren't particularly computationally expensive, the idea would be to avoid the step of storing them altogether and just calculate and use them as needed. Depends on the context of your problem, but often a good route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's encode the basis vectors with numbers: e1 -> 1, e2 -> 2, ... This allows a very memory-efficient storage.

```
M = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [3, 1, 3], [2, 3, 3]], dtype=np.uint8)  
# if more than 255 basis vectors, use uint16.
```

Now we only need to implement a special dot product that works with these basis vectors. Basically we only replace the multiplication with a comparison:

```
def basis_dot(a, b):
    return np.sum(a[:, :, np.newaxis] == b[np.newaxis, :, :], axis=1)

print(basis_dot(M, M.T))
# [[3 2 0 0]
#  [2 3 0 0]
#  [0 0 3 1]
#  [0 0 1 3]]
```

Let's verify the result:

```
M = np.array([[1,  0,  0,   0,  1,  0,   1,  0,  0],
              [1,  0,  0,   0,  1,  0,   0,  1,  0],
              [0,  0,  1,   1,  0,  0,   0,  0,  1],
              [0,  1,  0,   0,  0,  1,   0,  0,  1]])
np.dot(M, M.T)
# array([[3, 2, 0, 0],
#        [2, 3, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 3, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 3]])
```

A potential drawback with the approach is the large temporary array required in `basis_dot`. The memory requirement can be reduced by explicitly coding the loops, at the cost of performance (unless you use a jit compiler).

```
# slower but more memory friendly
def basis_dot(a, b):
    out = np.empty((a.shape[0], b.shape[1]))
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(b.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = np.sum(a[i, :] == b[:, j])
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

So, my assumption based on your example is that you're actually working with a higher dimensionality than just 3. My other assumption is that you're not computing any basis vectors, but just auto-generating basis vectors for RN. I'll ignore the question of exactly what you're trying to accomplish or why you're storing vectors that you can easily auto-generate for now.

If all of the above assumptions are accurate then you can likely gain a lot of benefit by storing in a sparse data format. This will only improve storage if you've got a preponderance of zeroes, but that seems like a reasonable assumption. There are a large number of sparse formats which you can view [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). My best guess for you would be the `coo_matrix` class.

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
new_matrix = coo_matrix(<your_matrix>)
```

Then saving new matrix in your format of choice.